# HTTP CONNECT stream.ReadToEnd takes infinite time

Tags: c#, stream, http-proxy

I'm trying to build a class which should be able to use HTTP CONNECT proxy tunnels.
My current code hangs at `DoHttpConnect() - "var retvar = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();"` and never reaches `Console.WriteLine(retvar);`

Connection class:

```
 public class HttpConnect : BaseProxyModule
{
    public HttpConnect(HostPortCollection proxyInformation) : base(proxyInformation)
    {
    }

    public override async Task<Stream> OpenStreamAsync(HostPortCollection dstSrv)
    {
        var socket = new TcpClient();
        if (await SwallowExceptionUtils.TryExec(() => socket.ConnectAsync(_proxyInformation.Addr, _proxyInformation.Port)) && socket.Connected)
        {
            var nStream = socket.GetStream();
            var cmd = ProxyCommandBuildUtils.GenerateHttpConnectCommand(dstSrv.Host, dstSrv.Port);

            await nStream.WriteAsync(cmd, 0, cmd.Length);
            var sr = new StreamReader(nStream);
            var cLine = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
            var fLineElem = cLine.Split(' ');

            if (fLineElem.Length >= 1 && fLineElem[1] == "200")
            {
                await sr.ReadLineAsync();
                return nStream;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    internal class ProxyCommandBuildUtils
    {
        private const string HTTP_PROXY_CONNECT_CMD = "CONNECT {0}:{1} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {0}\r\n\r\n";

        public static byte[] GenerateHttpConnectCommand(string host, int port)
        {
            string connectCmd = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, HTTP_PROXY_CONNECT_CMD, host, port.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            return connectCmd.GetBytes();
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
      public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DoHttpConnect().Wait();
        Debugger.Break();
    }

    public static async Task DoHttpConnect()
    {
        //var hCon = new HttpConnect(new HostPortCollection("5.135.195.166", 3128)); //Doesn't work..
        var hCon = new HttpConnect(new HostPortCollection("109.75.213.146", 53281)); //Doesn't work either :/
        var pStream = await hCon.OpenStreamAsync(new HostPortCollection("www.myip.ch", 80));
        var request = FormatHttpRequest(new Uri("http://www.myip.ch/"));
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(pStream))
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(pStream))
        {
            await sw.WriteLineAsync(request);

            var retvar = await sr.ReadToEndAsync(); //Takes till the end of time itself
            Console.WriteLine(retvar);
        }
        Debugger.Break();
    }
    private static string FormatHttpRequest(Uri url)
    {
        return $"GET {url.LocalPath}  HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: {url.DnsSafeHost}\r\n\r\n";
    }
```

Comment: Do you get a response at all, or does the streamreader wait till death for it?

Comment: @Nikolaus It doesn't get any response, so it waits until death. Just had a look at the wireshark protocols and it looks like "await sw.WriteLineAsync(request);" doesnt send anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WriteLineAsync()` call doesn't actually write out to the network immediately. Instead, the `StreamWriter` holds it in a buffer. Because of this, the server never actually gets your request, so won't send you a reply.

You should force the buffer to write out to the network by doing one of the following:

1. Turn on `AutoFlush` ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush(v=vs.110).aspx)) for the `StreamWriter`, which will make it flush the buffer with every call to `WriteLineAsync()`
2. Explicitly call `FlushAsync()` ([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flushasync(v=vs.110).aspx))
3. Close the stream (which will flush the buffer) by rewriting the code like this:

   ```
   using (var sr = new StreamReader(pStream))
   {
       using (var sw = new StreamWriter(pStream))
       {
           await sw.WriteLineAsync(request);
       }

       var retvar = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
       Console.WriteLine(retvar);
   }
   ```

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! I totally forgot about the neagle algorithm. One thing: when the streamwrite gets disposed, the basestream gets disposed aswell :/ Turning on Autoflush on the StreamWriter in the usage func did the job